# Libvirt VM Networking fails to start up after upgrading host from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: systemd, libvirt, ubuntu-20.04, dhclient

I upgraded a server from 18.04 to 20.04. I am using libvirt/kvm to host a number of VMs. Some of the VMs failed to reconnect to the network after the upgrade.

Two VMs in question run Ubuntu 18.04 and Centos 7 and both fail to start up networking after a reboot.
Both VMs connect successfully after I run "sudo dhclient"

```
$ ping 1.1.1.1
connect: Network is unreachable

$ sudo dhclient
cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.ej3Phm6q0A which is empty

$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=17.7 ms
```

Output of "systemctl status network" on Centos VM:

```
$ sudo systemctl status network
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-02-04 08:48:35 UTC; 31min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2524 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 04 08:48:35 centosvm network[2524]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 04 08:48:35 centosvm network[2524]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 04 08:48:35 centosvm network[2524]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 04 08:48:35 centosvm network[2524]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 04 08:48:35 centosvm network[2524]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 04 08:48:35 centosvm network[2524]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 04 08:48:35 centosvm systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 04 08:48:35 centosvm systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Feb 04 08:48:35 centosvm systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Feb 04 08:48:35 centosvm systemd[1]: network.service failed.
```

On the Ubuntu 18.04 VM:

```
$ sudo systemctl status -l systemd-networkd
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-02-02 11:23:50 UTC; 1 day 21h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 760 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─760 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Feb 04 09:22:10 ******* systemd-networkd[760]: vethf3988ae: Lost carrier
Feb 04 09:22:10 ubuntuvm systemd-networkd[760]: vethf3988ae: Link DOWN
Feb 04 09:22:11 ubuntuvm systemd-networkd[760]: br-32f293377024: Lost carrier
Feb 04 09:23:10 ubuntuvm systemd-networkd[760]: vethf7837d1: Link UP
Feb 04 09:23:11 ubuntuvm systemd-networkd[760]: vethf7837d1: Gained carrier
Feb 04 09:23:11 ubuntuvm systemd-networkd[760]: br-32f293377024: Gained carrier
Feb 04 09:23:12 ubuntuvm systemd-networkd[760]: vethf7837d1: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 04 09:23:12 ubuntuvm systemd-networkd[760]: vethf7837d1: Lost carrier
Feb 04 09:23:12 ubuntuvm systemd-networkd[760]: vethf7837d1: Link DOWN
Feb 04 09:23:13 ubuntuvm systemd-networkd[760]: br-32f293377024: Lost carrier
```

On the Ubuntu 20.04 host:

```
$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id STP enabled interfaces
...snip...
br0 8000.0cc47a228130 no enp4s0f0
       vnet0
       vnet1
       vnet2
       vnet3
       vnet5
...snip...
```

Both VMs have interfaces set up to connect to bridge br0:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:**********:90'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

Why are my VMs not able to connect after the host upgrade from 18.04 -> 20.04 and how can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like your bridge is up. Check your IP addresses and routes.

Comment: The host bridge br0 is definitely up and some VMs do not have any issues with connecting to the DHCP server and getting a lease. The two servers above manage to connect when I manually sudo dhclient but only until the next reboot. If I understand correctly systemd has a built-in DHCP client so dhclient will not normally be run at startup.